# Background image scale to screen size not to the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am setting the background image of each page using following JS

```
 var image = 'url(' + imageUrl + ') top left no-repeat fixed';
        $('body').css({ 'background': image });
```

By setting `"background-size:cover!important;"` able to scale the image according to the page content's height & width.

My requirement is to scale Background image according to screen size and not according to the page content size.

Basically I am facing problem in mobile view.

Comment: Please add fiddle link with your code, it will give more clarity.

Comment: body {height:100vh;}

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a background to the body. The body **is** the page content size.

If I were you I would create a `div` directly over the body.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="page-bg"></div>

  <!-- YOUR PAGE CONTENT -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-bg {
  max-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  /* your background styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS for body tag

```
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set size relative to viewport size using [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths).